# What is faster, raw CSS or inline styles in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Does the ReactJS virtual DOM make your app faster if you put all CSS as inline style? VS using raw .css files?

http://facebook.github.io/react/tips/inline-styles.html

Also see this ReactJS presentation on CSS in JavaScript:
https://speakerdeck.com/vjeux/react-css-in-js

Comment: Possibly related (also interesting reading) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8284365/external-css-vs-inline-style-performance-difference

Comment: found this interesting jsperf stuff 

http://jsperf.com/js-inline-css-vs-stylesheet-one-at-a-time/2 

Results say that stylesheets is faster than inline

Answer (score 13):

Browsers have put years of efforts into making their CSS stylesheet parsing + rendering engines blazing fast and memory efficient. Inline styles haven't exactly had that same treatment. However the bright side is that it actually doesn't matter much if you're creating normal-sized apps/pages. The difference is miniscule. Inline styles make up for the fact that 100% of the styles are actually used, where CSS stylesheets are often concatenated and almost 90% of the parsed rules are inactive (wasted).

Tip: Improve your performance by avoiding React re-renders. That's where the bottleneck often really is!