# css - style in head tag vs css file import - which is recommended?

Tags: html, css

I know that inline styles are strongly discouraged, and mostly we should use `<style>` tags in `<head>` or an external CSS file.

What I am not clear on is the usage of `<style>` tags in a `.html` file and actual `.css` files.

Should I move all style code from `home.html` to `home.css` and include it via the `<link>` tag?

Or using `<style>` tags in `<head>` perfectly acceptable? My boss says I should include all code in `.css` files.

**Note**:

I am not looking from a best-performance standpoint; rather clean code and best practices while writing HTML/CSS and facilitating better debugging/reading.

Comment: apply styles using class via CSS file is the best one.

Comment: you should check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8284365/external-css-vs-inline-style-performance-difference

Comment: @cst1992 put all your styles in CSS file, this is the best practices.

Comment: Read about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612483/whats-so-bad-about-in-line-css#answer-2612494

Comment: @PrajwalShrestha What about the case when you want to style only elements with id tags, or only elements with class tags?

Comment: @RockMyAlgorithm what I'm looking for is similar to yu_ominae's comment in the linked question.

Comment: there is for almost everthing a css selector available

Comment: Always do what your boss says.

Comment: Regarding to yu_ominae's comment, some parts are better to use inline styles, *e.g. User-defined content, result of Javascript functions, etc.* It's not practical to dynamically create separate CSS files just for these. But in general, this is a best practice. *In every rule, there is an exception.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should definitly take a look at this site: [Best practice of CSS](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/30-css-best-practices-for-beginners--net-6741) (not every point is compulsory in any case)

> Probably to add is that you should if your project gets bigger split
> your whole css file into multiple.
>
> Especially when splitting your files its getting usefull then its extremly convenient if you decided to separate your html and css. Otherwhise you're getting a huge html file und youre loosing the readability.

If you worked onces with css files of 8000lines youre thankful that you splitted up your css

Answer (score 0):

this below is example to separate ......

```css
/* .css file */

a {
    color: green;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!-- .html file -->

<a href="www.google.co.in">Google</a>
```

Comment: I already know the syntax and difference between the two; what I want to know is what experience dictates should be done to make the code easier to maintain and read.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer you create a seperate css file then you call the url in your html file inside the head tags like this:
...html file

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="www.google.co.in">Google</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

...CSS file

```
a { color: green; text-decoration: none;}
```

Having an external CSS is very much helpfull because you can call the file whenever you want to style another page without having to rewrite the code form scratch.