# CSS: transition properties in element itself?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

#### If i have applied a transition property to an element, i have to declare the properties in style tag, but how can i incorporate the whole declaration within the style attribute of the element?

```css
div {
background-color: teal;
padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
transition: all 1s;
}
div:hover {
background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

In the above example, **is it possible to simplify the code by including the transition property in style attribute of div element?**

Comment: but what about hover `:hover`??

Comment: @לבנימלכה that's the problem

Comment: Also read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8284365/external-css-vs-inline-style-performance-difference

Comment: @Abhishek I mean why do it inside tag if you have css allready ???

Comment: we don't have any method to use pseudo in inline css.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1033166/7512762

Comment: @לבנימלכה i just want to try it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have all the declarations inside the style tag. However, the pseudo classes do not work inside the style attribute of the element.

You can possibly use the below snippet as a workaround or else define it in the stylesheet ofcourse.

```html
<div style="width: 100%; height: 50px; background-color: red; transition: all 1s" onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='yellow';" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='red';">
</div>
```

Comment: thank you, its js but it helped

Comment: if you do not want use css you must use js/jquery to mouse hover event

Comment: @AnkitSharma ok bro, you did nice job