# I want to know something about Inline CSS and External CSS

Tags: html, css

Inline CSS is the CSS that is added inside an HTML element ,and
External CSS is usually the best practice when writing CSS because it keeps everything organized

is it true ?

Comment: that's a 1 sec search information though. you'll find some details here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/8284398/11168176

Comment: It's complicated. For email templates, inline styles are good (for better compatibility). For the web, internal styles and external styles are better than inline styles - just to reuse the styles.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time. If you need CSS styling for multiple files it will make it cleaner and it will be easier to manage. If you need styling for only one file then you can use inline CSS.