# Is external css file really more performant than style tag?

Tags: css, browser

I heard that external css file can be cached by the browser so it improve performance of the web.

My question is that is it real?

Will cached css file really improve the performance?

Comment: Cached means that it doesn'n need to be downloaded again from the server. Why do you think that's not helping?

Comment: Cached file will skip the network request. That's straightforward. But i think that's just network thing, not a matter of user-centric performance. So I am curious that external css file really performant than style tag during browser rendering pileline. Sorry my question was not concrete.

Comment: But your question specifically mentioned "CSS file can be cached, which improves performance. Does [caching] really improve performance"? "Download speed" is something that's very noticable for users

Comment: Yes you're right. Fast download is good for users.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8284365/external-css-vs-inline-style-performance-difference
Read this post

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, browsers will try to cache CSS style sheets (within limitation) so that it's only fetched once, and served on demand. This saves network bandwidth.

It can be assumed that CSS will not change much compared to the content of the website. Therefore, depending on the implementation, splitting the style definitions away from the content, especially if designed for reusability is often the ideal approach.

Answer (score 0):

No, it **doesn't change anything** even for loading time!

As all files are cached by default (even the HTML), loading time doesn't change.

And the browser doesn't care about where you put your style.

Traditionally, using the `style` tag or `style` attribute is not recommended but it is related to the readability of the code only. This does not change anything for the user.

Comment: And what happens if you change your HTML but not the stylesheet? Then the CSS must be loaded again as part of the HTML file. As external file, only the changed HTML needs to be reloaded

Comment: If you change HTML but not CSS, then only the HTML file will be reloaded. So if your CSS is inside the HTML file, then all is reloaded.

Comment: Exactly, which is in stark contrast with the first sentence of this answer ("it doesn't change anything, even for loading time").

Comment: But why CSS will be changed on the server ???

Comment: Because you decide that your website needs a new layout or different colors? I'm not sure I understand that last question

Comment: It almost never happens, so except in this very rare case, it doesn't change anything. Do what you want.